# Unziping a File using SSIS

Tags: sql, csv, ssis, zip

I have a .zip file that is coming from a Web Service that emails the file monthly to an email address. The Email has a scripted macro that drops the .zip file into a specific folder.

What I need is an SSIS package that unzips this file, saves the single internal document (a .csv file that will also need to be renamed) and then Processing the transformation package that I have put together.

At the end, I also need to have the .zip file moved to a specific folder.

I'm sure a foreach loop container is involved in this but thats as far as I got.

I looked through the net and found several ways to do this but I want to avoid C# as I am not familiar with this language just yet.

FileName: HRIS_LMSUtilization_532_04_22_2014_15_22.zip
Internal File: HRIS_LMSUtilization_532_04_22_2014_15_22.csv (need this renamed to just HRIS_LMSUtilization.csv)

File Path on server: E:\DATABASES\DATAWAREHOUSE\UNIVERSAL_DW\HRIS\HRIS_EEIMPORT\
This is where the .zip file is and where the extracted file will need to go.

Archived File: E:\DATABASES\DATAWAREHOUSE\UNIVERSAL_DW\HRIS\HRIS_EEIMPORT\ARCHIVED\
This is where the .zip file will need to go once the Internal file is extracted.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try an Execute Process task using 7-zip or some other zip software with a command line processor?

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted the process to check a specific folder and then perform an operation to each file (unzip, load, move file), you are correct about the 'foreach loop container'.

In the foreach loop, set the enumerator to be 'Foreach File Enumerator' and specify the folder and file mask (maybe HRIS_LMSUtilization_*.zip in your case). In the "Variable Mappings" create a variable (User::file_name) which will store the file name in each iteration of the loop.

Within the bounds of the foreach loop, you will need to wire up:

1. A task to unzip and rename the file... you will likely need to use the a task that can access the command line to do the unzipping unless you have a custom zip task like the one from CozyRoc.
2. Whatever processing tasks you need performed on the file (you mention another package for this).
3. A file system task that will move the file to "E:\DATABASES\DATAWAREHOUSE\UNIVERSAL_DW\HRIS\HRIS_EEIMPORT\ARCHIVED\"

There doesn't seem to be any need to use C# to accomplish what it sounds like you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

for unzipping you could use a Execute Process Task that executes a batch file or an unzip tool or you could use third party tasks (free or commercial):

http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2012/10/custom-ssis-component-unzip-task.html
http://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/zip-task
[image]